# 500 (Internal Server Error) when i display the data from the variable in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got this error.

```
GET http://localhost:3000/activities/undefined 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

In browser console log.
When i tried to display the data by this variable in my .erb template file.

```
<h1><%= @activity.name %></h1>
```

This is my controller method.

```
def activities_details

   @activity = Activity.find_by(id: params[:id])
   @temple = Temple.find_by(id: @activity.temple_id)

   render :template => 'front_pages/activity_details'
end
```

This page still works fine but i still confusing why this error keeps happening.

#

I found the reason it seems like rails call 
get request from my link twice.
First time is the correct request,but second time is the wrong one.
this is log from the server

```
Started GET "/activities/24" for ::1 at 2016-02-22 14:19:13 +0800
Processing by FrontPagesController#activities_details as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"24"}
  Activity Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "activities".* FROM "activities" WHERE "activities"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "activities"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 24]]
  Temple Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "temples".* FROM "temples" WHERE "temples"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "temples"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 7]]
  Rendered front_pages/activity_details.html.erb within layouts/application (0.3ms)
  Rendered shared/_header.html.erb (3.8ms)
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 419ms (Views: 414.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)


Started GET "/assets/shutterstock_96393731.jpg" for ::1 at 2016-02-22 14:19:13 +0800


Started GET "/activities/undefined" for ::1 at 2016-02-22 14:19:13 +0800
Processing by FrontPagesController#activities_details as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"undefined"}
  Activity Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "activities".* FROM "activities" WHERE "activities"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "activities"."created_at" DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 0]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `temple_id' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/front_pages_controller.rb:36:in `activities_details'
```

This is my link from the previous page.

```
<%= link_to "Details", activity_show_path(activity.id) ,class: "btn_1"%>
```

My routes

```
get '/activities/:id' => 'front_pages#activities_details', :as => 'activity_show'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Paste your complete development log

Comment: ah i found the reasons. Let me check it first.

Comment: @RORDeveloper already provide server log pls take a look, thanks!

Comment: params[:id] is undefined and that is why it is giving error. How are you sending id from link_to?

Comment: This is my link.

<a class="btn_1" href="/activities/6">Details</a>

and it works fine but seem like after the first request with the correct one it tried to send the request with an empty id.

Comment: check whether activity.id is available for that page

Comment: yeah i found the reason bec of some of my javascript. thanks!